# JavaFX custom listView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, cellrenderer

I wanted to ask the best way to make a ListView with custom objects in JavaFX, I want a list that each item looks like this:

[image]

I searched and found that most people do it with the cell factory method. Is ther any other way? For example with a custome fxml?

**Here's my fmxl archive**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="557.0" prefWidth="1012.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0288D1;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="desktop_tasker.FXMLTaskerController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="-8.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="1027.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EEEEEE;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="28.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <ListView fx:id="list_todo" onEditStart="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="527.0" prefWidth="502.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="527.0" prefWidth="640.0">
               <children>
                  <ListView fx:id="list_done" onEditStart="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="527.0" prefWidth="502.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="1012.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**And here's my Object Task:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Usuario on 26/10/2017.
 */

public class Task implements Comparable<Task> {
    private String title;
    private String attendant;
    private String comment;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    private String creationDate;
    private boolean state;
    private boolean visible;

    public Task(String title, String attendant, String comment, String description, int priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.attendant = attendant;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.creationDate = setCreationDate();
        this.state = false;
        this.visible = true;
    }

    public Task(String title, String attendant, String comment, String description, int priority, String date, boolean state, boolean visible) {
        this.title = title;
        this.attendant = attendant;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.creationDate = date;
        this.state = state;
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    private static String setCreationDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        return sdf.format(date);
    }


    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAttendant() {
        return attendant;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public boolean isState() {
        return state;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", attendant='" + attendant + '\'' +
                ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", priority=" + priority +
                ", creationDate='" + creationDate + '\'' +
                ", state=" + state +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Task task = (Task) o;

        if (priority != task.priority) return false;
        if (state != task.state) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(task.title) : task.title != null) return false;
        if (attendant != null ? !attendant.equals(task.attendant) : task.attendant != null)
            return false;
        if (comment != null ? !comment.equals(task.comment) : task.comment != null) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(task.description) : task.description != null)
            return false;
        return creationDate != null ? creationDate.equals(task.creationDate) : task.creationDate == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (attendant != null ? attendant.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (comment != null ? comment.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + priority;
        result = 31 * result + (creationDate != null ? creationDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (state ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo( Task task) {
        int comparePrior = this.getPriority() - (task.getPriority());
        return comparePrior == 0 ? this.getTitle().compareTo(task.getTitle()) : comparePrior;
    }

}
```

I want the items to look like individual containers, but I didn't find any way to do it. Any recommendations on what to use? And what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question here? You need a cell factory for this.

Comment: That's right with a custom cell factory. Nothing stops you from defining content in FXML.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an example of using `FXML` to create custom `ListCell`

First, a controller is created to inherit `ListCell`. In the constructor of this controller we load the `FXML` statement on its view.

```
public class TaskCell extends ListCell<Task> {

    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label commentLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;

    public TaskCell() {
        loadFXML();
    }

    private void loadFXML() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("task_cell.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
        else {
            titleLabel.setText(item.getTitle());
            commentLabel.setText(item.getComment());
            descriptionLabel.setText(item.getDescription());

            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view - *task_cell.fxml*

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.ListCell" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <graphic>
        <VBox>
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="titleLabel" />
                <VBox>
                    <children>
                        <Label fx:id="commentLabel" />
                        <Label fx:id="descriptionLabel"/>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

Then you need to create a cell factory that can be used to create cells.

```
public class TaskCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<Task>, ListCell<Task>> {

    @Override
    public ListCell<Task> call(ListView<Task> param) {
        return new TaskCell();
    }
}
```

Once we have the factory, we can manually submit it to `ListView` using the `ListView#setCellFactory()`

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Task> listView;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        listView.setCellFactory(new TaskCellFactory());
    }
}
```

оr we can describe it in the `FXML` statement of the view that contains the `ListView` control

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <ListView fx:id="listView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
        <cellFactory>
            <TaskCellFactory />
        </cellFactory>
    </ListView>
</GridPane>
```

In the second version, the **intellij idea** marks the wrong line with `<TaskCellFactory />` but this is clearly an error in the xml parser.

Comment: It works! The problem I have is that the items of the list can't be selected. Any idea why?

Comment: @Green_Sam The selection is done in the `updateItem()` function (specifically in `super.updateItem(item, empty);`). If it does not work correctly, you can do it yourself using `isSelected()` and change the background of the cell to whether it is selected or not.

Comment: Thanks again! One last question, I want to set an event handler for when an item of listview is clicked (and I want the information of the item to be accesible), where should I put the events?

Comment: If you are not interested in an event from a particular element inside the cell, use `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)` according to what you need

Comment: good answer - with a slight flaw: cell's should cope with null item, always