# JavaFX listview doesn't show custom listcell and instead returns an empty list

Tags: java, listview, javafx

So I've tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511132/javafx-custom-listview) as closely as I could but when I run my program it just displays an empty listview, instead of my custom listcells; and without showing any error.

[Big light grey rectangle in the middle is the listview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnu3M.png)

Here is my code:-

Main FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="1045.0" prefWidth="1770.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E2E2E;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.BuyerVendors">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="70.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1630.0" style="-fx-background-color: #404040;">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <children>
            <ListView fx:id="listview" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1630.0" style="-fx-background-color: #404040;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Listcell FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<fx:root maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1630.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1630.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1630.0" style="-fx-background-color: #404040;" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="name" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="35.0" maxHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Abc Xyz Fresh Greens" textFill="WHITE" underline="true">
         <font>
            <Font size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="address" alignment="TOP_LEFT" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="100.0" maxHeight="63.0" maxWidth="600.0" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="East of Trodden, 910 019." textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="36.0" layoutX="1000.0" layoutY="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../icons/star.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="stars" layoutX="1050.0" layoutY="45.0" text="4.9/5" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="reviews" layoutX="1100.0" layoutY="45.0" text="(200 reviews)" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="email" layoutX="1000.0" layoutY="103.0" text="Contact: abc.xyz@gmail.com" textFill="WHITE" />
   </children>
   <cursor>
      <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
   </cursor>
</fx:root>
```

Main controller class along with object 'Vendors' and listcell controller class:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

//Controller class for Vendors listview
public class BuyerVendors implements Initializable {

    
    //Getters, setters and constructor for list/listview object
    public static class Vendors {

        String email, name, address, no_of_reviews, rating;

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        public void setRating(String rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public String getNo_of_reviews() {
            return no_of_reviews;
        }

        public void setNo_of_reviews(String no_of_reviews) {
            this.no_of_reviews = no_of_reviews;
        }

        public Vendors(String email, String name, String address, String rating, String no_of_reviews) {
            super();
            this.email = email;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.rating = rating;
            this.no_of_reviews = no_of_reviews;
        }

    }

    
    ObservableList<Vendors> list;

    //Controller class for Vendors listcell
    public class VendorsCell extends ListCell<Vendors> {

        @FXML
        private Label name;

        @FXML
        private Label address;

        @FXML
        private Label stars;

        @FXML
        private Label reviews;

        @FXML
        private Label email;
        
        public VendorsCell() {
            loadFXML();
        }

        private void loadFXML() {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../FXML files/VendorsCell.fxml"));
                loader.setController(this);
                loader.setRoot(this);
                loader.load();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Vendors item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(empty) {
                setText(null);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }

            else {
                name.setText(item.getName());
                address.setText(item.getAddress());
                if(item.getRating() == null) {
                    stars.setText("No ratings yet");
                    reviews.setText("");
                }
                else {
                    stars.setText(item.getRating());
                    reviews.setText(item.getNo_of_reviews());
                }

                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    //CellFactory
    public class VendorsCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<Vendors>, ListCell<Vendors>> {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Vendors> call(ListView<Vendors> param) {
            return new VendorsCell();
        }
    }
    
    
    @FXML
    private ListView<Vendors> listview;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        
        try {
            list = UserDB.displayVendors(); // Function that returns observable list from database 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listview = new ListView<Vendors>(list);
        listview.setCellFactory(new VendorsCellFactory());
    }

}
```

PS: Please excuse me if there are some silly errors; I don't have much experience using javaFX or java itself. :(

Comment: work through a tutorial about using fxml .. (you __must not__ instantiate fields that are to be injected - here the listView)

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, don't you get `ClassCastException`s from this? You declared the `fx:root` with `type="AnchorPane"`, but you set the root to an instance of a `ListCell` (which is not an `AnchorPane`). Surely you want `type="ListCell"` and then to declare the `AnchorPane` in the FXML for the cell; then in `updateItem()` set the graphic to the `AnchorPane`.

Comment: This looks suspicious. `"../FXML files/VendorsCell.fxml"`. See -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder